# Asymptotic behavior of a sequence given by a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, asymptotics, generating-functions

Original problem is to determine asymptotic behavior of ${a_i}\left( t \right)$ as $t \to \infty $ given by recurrence relations

${a_1}\left( 0 \right) = 1$

${a_1}\left( t \right) = \frac{{2t + 1}}{{2t}}{a_1}\left( {t - 1} \right)$

${a_i}\left( t \right) = \frac{{2t + 1}}{{2t}}{a_i}\left( {t - 1} \right) + \frac{1}{{2t}}{a_{i - 1}}\left( {t - 1} \right)$

for $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt at solution:

Generating function for ${a_i}$ is $\displaystyle{F_i}\left( x \right) = \frac{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{ - \frac{3}
{2}}}{{\ln }^{i - 1}}\frac{1}
{{1 - x}}}}
{{\left( {2i - 2} \right)!!}}$.

If we rewrite recurrence relations in a different way:

${a_1}\left( t \right) - {a_1}\left( {t - 1} \right) = \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_1}\left( {t - 1} \right)$

${a_i}\left( t \right) - {a_i}\left( {t - 1} \right) = \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_i}\left( {t - 1} \right) + \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_{i - 1}}\left( {t - 1} \right)$

And then pretend that difference operator is differential operator

${a_1}^\prime \left( t \right) = \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_1}\left( t \right)$

${a_i}^\prime \left( t \right) = \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_i}\left( t \right) + \frac{1}
{{2t}}{a_{i - 1}}\left( t \right)$

by solving a system of differential equations, we get ${a_i}\left( t \right) = \frac{{\sqrt {1 + t} {{\ln }^{i - 1}}\left( {1 + t} \right)}}
{{\left( {2i - 2} \right)!!}}$. Now we define ${G_i} = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt {1 + t} {{\ln }^{i - 1}}\left( {1 + t} \right)}}
{{\left( {2i - 2} \right)!!}}{x^t}} $.

It turns out that (see http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/twenty.pdf , page 210-211) if ${L_i} = \frac{{{G_i}\left( x \right)}}
{{{F_i}\left( x \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1 - } \frac{{\sum\limits_{t = 1}^\infty  {\sqrt t {x^t}{{\ln }^{i - 1}}t} }}
{{x{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{ - \frac{3}
{2}}}{{\ln }^{i - 1}}\frac{1}
{{1 - x}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1 - } \frac{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{\frac{3}
{2}}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\sqrt k {x^k}{{\ln }^{i - 1}}k} }}
{{{{\ln }^{i - 1}}\frac{1}
{{1 - x}}}}$ exists and is nonzero, then $\displaystyle\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } {a_i}\left( t \right) \cdot \frac{{\left( {2i - 2} \right)!! \cdot {L_i}}}
{{\sqrt {t + 1} {{\ln }^{i - 1}}\left( {t + 1} \right)}} = 1$. For several values of ${L_i}$ this seems to be true, which strikes me as unexpected.

For $i = 1$ wolfram's mathematica returns ${L_1} = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}$, but can not evaluate other expressions. However, they are around 0.9 and rising as $i$ rises.

My question is how to analytically evaluate ${L_i}$, or alternatively, disregarding the previous arguments, how to determine asymptotic behavior of a sequence ${a_i}\left( t \right)$?

More generally, is it usual that the solutions of difference and corresponding differential equation (given by replacing difference operator with differential operator) have the same asymptotic behavior up to a multiplicative constant? If that is the case and such behavior is well understood, are there any textbooks about it?

Comment: You may be interested in *Analytical Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick, which you can download [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html); about half of it is about extracting asymptotics of sequences from their generating functions.

Comment: I upvoted your only answer (didn't understand all of it but it looked good and the OP was happy about it :-); now you have enough reputation to comment directly under David's answer. a) That would be easier to follow and b) I don't know whether David gets notified if you ping him like this in a thread where he hasn't commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a generating function $q(x)$, you can often find the asymptotic behavior of its coefficients by using the Cauchy integral formula to equate the $n$th coefficient to $(2\pi i)^{-1}$ times the integral of $q(x)/x^{n+1}$ around a suitable contour, and then estimating the integral.  If $q(x)$ has one singularity which is closer to the origin than all other singularities, the asymptotics of the coefficients of $q(x)$ will be determined by the behavior of $q(x)$ near this singularity, and the contour of integration should be chosen to approach this singularity.  This method ("singularity analysis") is explained in detail in [the Flajolet and Sedgewick book mentioned above.](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html)  In particular, given the generating function $F_i(x)$ above, their Theorem VI.2 says that, for each fixed $i$, $$a_i(t)=[x^t]F_i(x)\sim\frac{2\sqrt{t} (\log t)^{i-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2i-2)!!}.$$
So, $L_i$ is $\sqrt{\pi}/2$, regardless of $i$.

Comment: Theorem VI.2 is for a generating function which has an additional term $\frac{1}{{{z^\beta }}}$. Could you please explain in more detail how did you get your result? Also, thank you both for the book recommendation, and yoriki for upvote

Comment: Sorry, after carefully reading that page in the book, I realized that term $\frac{1}{{{z^\beta }}}$ doesn't change asymptotics of GF near 1. Thank you for your answer